# How to know if exif gps tag was modified on android?

Tags: android, image, gps, exif, last-modified

I have observed that you can change image location from android. How do I know if gps data was modified? I have researched and only got how to get the image metadata, but no tag specifying that the gps was modified.

Comment: There is no change tracking of EXIF header data in a JPEG file, just as there is no change tracking of text data in a text file. So, you have no way to know for a given JPEG image whether any given EXIF header has changed from any prior edition of that EXIF header.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.